# How to check if something is done then do not do it again if it is existing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make like that, when on `.content`, then create a new one and attach to `.mainPage` but just want to append only once.

Here is the sample
http://jsfiddle.net/4Qs97/

```
<div class="mainPage">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

var $newDiv = '<div class="content">This</div>';

$('.content').on('mouseover', function(){
  $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');
});
```

I understand I can use `one` to achieve that, but wanted to know if there is way to use "on" to achieve the same goal, just append once if action is already made :-)

Thanks

Comment: Checkout my answer. You can achieve it by simply removing the 'content' class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *flag* `variable` to remember of element is added.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/4Qs97/1/)**

```
var $newDiv = '<div class="content">This</div>';
alreadyAdded = false;
$('.content').on('mouseover', function(){
    if(alreadyAdded) return;
  $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');
    alreadyAdded = true;
});
```

Comment: You can use "one()" as answered by @Felix so that no need to use variable to know if action done or not. But still it is good answer by you.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, the OP knows about the one and he has mentioned in his question "I understand I can use one to achieve that,"

Comment: No worries, one() seems better option, he probably want to know an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**:

```
var $newDiv = '<div class="content">This</div>';

$('.content').one('mouseover', function () {
    $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qs97/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qs97/2/)**

In this scenario you have to use  **one**

. but as you requirement i used flag variable for that

```
  var $newDiv = '<div class="content">This</div>';
    var isAppend=false;

 $('.content').on('mouseover', function(){
        if(!isAppend){
            isAppend=true;

            $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by simply removing the class.

```
var $newDiv = '<div class="content">This</div>';
$('.content').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('content');
  $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');        
});
```

Live Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/5DNTP/

Answer (score 0):

If the event listener's only purpose is to `append`, remove it using `off`, but then again it is the same as `one`

```
$('.content').on('mouseover', function(){
  $($newDiv).appendTo('.mainPage');
  $(this).off('mouseover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Qs97/5/